# Ajax get not returning to success or error on second get call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, printing

I have "print" button which calls ajax get and opens up page in new window to print.

```
<button type="button"  onclick="getPrint(event , 'Id')">Print</button>

 function getPrint(e, Id) {        
        var url = '/PrintController/Print/' + "?Id=" + id;

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success == true) {
                    var mywindow = window.open('', 'Print', 'height=500,width=600,menubar=yes');
                    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
                    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
                    mywindow.document.write($('<div></div>').append(data.viewBody).clone().html());
                    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
                    mywindow.focus();
                    mywindow.print();
                    mywindow.close();
                }
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
        return;
}
```

The controller returns as below :-

```
return Json(new { success = true, viewBody = viewPrintSub }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

The very first time i click "Print" button , it works fine. it does ajax get and control goes to action method and returns success and then it comes back to view and goes inside success function and opens up new window,

But on second click , it goes to controller action method and then it returns success and then this time it does not goes to success or error at all.

Comment: Are you watching the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: Why don't you just pass the URL to `window.open`, without the AJAX? Do you just need to strip out out the `<head>`?

Comment: Try changing `return;` to `return false;`

Comment: I'd suggest you put a `console.log(data.success)` at the start of your success handler.  In your code if `data.success` is anything other than `true`, your code does nothing.

Comment: it does return {"success":true,"viewBody":"\r\n\u....in response when i check browser console.
it works first time , but doesn't work on second time clicking of print button. Second time eventhough i see true in browser response, but the control never goes inside if (data.success == true) ..

Answer (score 0):

Did you resolve this? I would suggest that you set caching to false, and of course ensure that the browser is not preventing the site from opening multiple windows.

```
function getPrint(e, Id) {        
    var url = '/PrintController/Print/' + "?Id=" + id;

    $.ajax({
        cache: false, // Do not cache
        url: url,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success == true) {
                var mywindow = window.open('', 'Print', 'height=500,width=600,menubar=yes');
                mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
                mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
                mywindow.document.write($('<div></div>').append(data.viewBody).clone().html());
                mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
                mywindow.focus();
                mywindow.print();
                mywindow.close();
            }
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
    return;
```

}